# VHDL Modelsim: Array lengths do not match (null array vs array of length 8)

Tags: arrays, vhdl, fpga, modelsim

I was wondering why I am some of my std_logic_vectors are showing up as null vectors especially when I specified the length already. I'd appreciate any help possible

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.numeric_std.ALL;
entity counter8bits is
port(counter_enable, rst, clk : IN std_logic; counter_out : OUT std_logic_vector(7 to 0));
end entity counter8bits;

architecture counting_arc of counter8bits is
signal current_count : std_logic_vector(7 to 0);
type jstate is (nullState, start0, start1, change01, change10);
signal present_state : jstate;
signal next_state: jstate := nullState;



signal int_count: integer := 0;
begin

present_state <= next_state when clk'event and clk = '1';

current_count <= std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(int_count, 8)) when rising_edge(clk);
counter_out <= current_count;
stacking: process(present_state)
begin

next_state <= present_state;
int_count <= 0 when int_count = 255;    
                    case present_state is
                    
                        when nullState =>
                            if counter_enable = '0' then
                                next_state <= start0;
                            else
                                next_state <= start1;
                            end if;
                        
                        when start0 =>
                            if counter_enable = '1' then
                                next_state <= change01;
                                int_count <= int_count + 1;
                            else
                                next_state <= start0;
                            end if;
                        
                        when start1 =>
                            if counter_enable = '0' then
                                next_state <= change10;
                                int_count <= int_count + 1;
                            else
                                next_state <= start1;
                            end if;
                        
                        when change01 =>
                            if counter_enable = '0' then
                                next_state <= change10;
                                int_count <= int_count + 1;
                            else
                                next_state <= start1;
                            end if;
                        
                        when change10 =>
                            if counter_enable = '1' then
                                next_state <= change01;
                                int_count <= int_count + 1;
                            else
                                next_state <= start0;
                            end if;
                        when others =>
                            next_state <= nullState;                    

end case;

end process stacking;
end architecture counting_arc;
```

Here is the error: Fatal: (vsim-3420) Array lengths do not match. Left is 0 (7 to 0 (null array)). Right is 8 (7 downto 0).

Left refers to current_count and counter_out

Comment: This would be a simulation error that can't be duplicated without a [mcve], here providing a testbench. `signal current_count : std_logic_vector(7 to 0);`  has a null range (IEEE Std 1076-2008 5.3.2.2 Index constraints and discrete ranges). Change the `7 to 0` to `7 downto 0`.  Without wondering why or asking for nebulous help consider [ask], providing a minimal, complete, and verifiable example as well as a specific question. There isn't a duplicate question with a null range.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A null range occurs when you specify the values in the wrong direction.  Here you have specified both `current_count` and `counter_out` as `7 to 0`. Using `to` is an ascending range,  hence the first number should be the lower one.  Similarly,  `downto` is a descending range and should have the higher value on the left.

Here,  I suggest you replace  `to` with `downto`, as this is generally convention.